# How to create new column of repeating sequence based on other column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a the following dataframe:

```
Participant_ID      Order
1                     A 
1                     A 
2                     B 
2                     B 
3                     A 
3                     A 
4                     B 
4                     B 
5                     B 
5                     B
6                     A 
6                     A
```

Every two rows refer to the same participant. I want to create a new column based on the value in the column 'Order'. If the 'Order' == A, then I want it to create a new column with two rows of [1, 2], and then if the 'Order' == B, then I want it to create two rows of [2,1] in the same column

The preferred output would be the following:

```
Participant_ID      Order   Period
1                     A       1
1                     A       2
2                     B       2
2                     B       1
3                     A       1
3                     A       2
4                     B       2
4                     B       1
5                     B       2
5                     B       1
6                     A       1
6                     A       2
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't really understand why your output data frame does not have twice as many rows as your input data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of possibilities. This assumes that `Order` value is same for a given `Participant_ID`. If this isn't the case, you will need to include additional logic.

You can use `if_else`:

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>%
  group_by(Participant_ID) %>%
  mutate(Period = if_else(Order == "A", 1:2, 2:1))
```

Or to explicitly check for multiple different values (e.g., "A", "B", etc.), have more flexibility, and include `NA` for other cases, you can use `case_when`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Participant_ID) %>%
  mutate(Period = case_when(
    Order == "A" ~ 1:2,
    Order == "B" ~ 2:1,
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_
  ))
```

**Output**

```
   Participant_ID Order Period
            <int> <chr>  <int>
 1              1 A          1
 2              1 A          2
 3              2 B          2
 4              2 B          1
 5              3 A          1
 6              3 A          2
 7              4 B          2
 8              4 B          1
 9              5 B          2
10              5 B          1
11              6 A          1
12              6 A          2
```